# conexion con base de datos y servidor

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, msql, mysql-sever

estoy tratando de hacer una conexion, estoy trabjando directo con un servidor que se llama alwaysdata para mandar whatsapp pero quiero que cuando se respondan esos whatsapp se guarden en la base de datos, el problema es que creo que estoy haciendo la conexion mal, intente hacer la conexion con mi BD local y con la del servidor pero no me guardan nada, el problema que tengo con el servidor que ocupo que es alwaysdata es que no me dice el ip del host ni el puerto que ocupa espero que me puedan ayudar ya que es la primera vez que hago conexiones en el servidor poder hacer la conexion
`
este es parte de mi controller

```
public function recibe(){
//LEEMOS LOS DATOS ENVIADOS
$respuesta = file_get_contents("php://input")
//SI NO HAY DATOS NOS SALIMOS
if($respuesta==null){
exit;
}
//CONVERTIMOS EL JSON EN ARRAY DE PHP
$respuesta = json_decode($respuesta, true);
$mensaje=$respuesta\['entry'\]\[0\]\['changes'\]\[0\]\['value'\]\['messages'\]\[0\]\['text'\]\['body'\];
//EXTRAEMOS EL TELEFONO DEL ARRAY
$telefonoCliente=$respuesta\['entry'\]\[0\]\['changes'\]\[0\]\['value'\]\['messages'\]\[0\]\['from'\];
//EXTRAEMOS EL ID DE WHATSAPP DEL ARRAY
$id=$respuesta\['entry'\]\[0\]\['changes'\]\[0\]\['value'\]\['messages'\]\[0\]\['id'\];
//EXTRAEMOS EL TIEMPO DE WHATSAPP DEL ARRAY
$timestamp=$respuesta\['entry'\]\[0\]\['changes'\]\[0\]\['value'\]\['messages'\]\[0\]\['timestamp'\];
//SI HAY UN MENSAJE
if($mensaje!=null){
file_put_contents("text.txt", $mensaje);
echo $mensaje;
require_once './enviar.php';
//ENVIAMOS LA RESPUESTA VIA WHATSAPP
enviar($mensaje,$id,$timestamp,$telefonoCliente);
}

//funcion que hace la conexion
function enviar($recibido, $idWA,$timestamp,$telefonoCliente) {
require_once './conexion.php';
$sql = "INSERT INTO registro "
. "(mensaje_recibido    ,id_wa        ,timestamp_wa        ,     telefono_wa) VALUES "
. "('" . $recibido . "' ,'" . $idWA . "','" . $timestamp . "','" . $telefonoCliente . "');";
$conn->query($sql);
$conn->close();
}

//otro archivo con la conexion

<?php
$servername = "mysql-vdmc.alwaysdata.net";
$username = "vdmc";
$password = 
$dbname = "vdmc_wa";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//como configure.env

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=vdmc_wa
DB_USERNAME=vdmc
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer algo así y checar si se está conectando primeramente ya que si no te mostrará un texto con el error:

```
$conn = new mysqli("mysql-vdmc.alwaysdata.net", "vdmc", "", "vdmc_wa");
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
}
return $conn;
```